# Creating Positioned Filled In Boxes & Setting Height & Width

Tags: html, css, position, fill, box

I'm new to html & css & I'm trying to create colored filled in boxes to put within a border box. I need to be able to set them at a certain width and height. I also need to set them 2px apart each & 6px away from the border. I've attatched a picture of what I'm trying to do. Is there a way to do this with CSS? Something like the html id=filled & CSS #filled or to do this with only html? Picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4dZi.png

I couldn't post the html here because of the 'your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code' error, even though it was. Here's the html: http://pastebin.com/GFRqeRa9

Thanks! Any help is appreciated! =)

Answer (score 0):

I have found one div tag in your code as follows :

```
<div style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(43,43,43); padding: 5px 8px; text-align: center;">
<div style="text-align: left;">
<span style="font-size: large;"><b>text</b></span></div>
</div>
```

It is not possible to develope whole design you want but I have change this code as follows :

```
<div style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(43,43,43); padding: 2px 0px 0px 6px; text-align: center;margin-bottom: 2px;">
                                            <div style="text-align: left;">
                                                <span style="font-size: large;"><b>text</b></span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
```

Suggestion is, create a CSS class for common style effects and now you need to create hover effect to this div for green color hover effect (as you put in image for your expected output)

Comment: Oh, I was going to make it green later. This code looks nicer than mine, thanks. I figured out how to put space between the boxes, you use `<div class="verticalgap" style="height:2px"></div>` I also figured out how to set the height and width of the div tag. I put this inside the div style tag. `; height: 100px; width: 100px">`.  I'm still unsure how to set how far away the div tag is away from the border though. Any way to do that? Thanks.

Comment: You can set padding for the <td> that contains the <div>. Set it more than 0 so it will increase the space between table border and div.

Comment: I tried the html `<table id="t1"><tr id="t1"><td id="t1"><tbody id="t1">` & css `#t1 {
 padding:2px;
}` but it doesn't seem to change anything. I put it just before `<table bgcolor="black" border="0" cellpadding="2" width="500"><tbody><tr><td class="e"> <table border="0"><tbody><tr><td> ` but it didn't work. I changed the cellpadding which seemed to changed the padding a bit though. Anything that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You can not assign same id "id="t1" to multiple elements. Can you give exact idea what you want?